# Linker errors, undefined reference to LAPACK subroutines while compiling library (CMU sphinx3)

Tags: static-linking, lapack, cmusphinx

I'm encountering the following error messages while trying to compile the sphinx3 module of the [cmu sphinx toolkit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/)

```
Making all in programs
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Downloads/src/cmusphinx-code/sphinx3/src/programs'
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CC    --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -Wall -fvisibility=hidden    -o sphinx3_decode.exe main_decode.o ../../src/libs3decoder/libs3decoder.la  -lsphinxbase -lsphinxad -lm 
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -o .libs/sphinx3_decode.exe main_decode.o  ../../src/libs3decoder/.libs/libs3decoder.a -lsphinxbase -lsphinxad
/usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.a(matrix.o): In function `determinant':
/cygdrive/c/Downloads/src/cmusphinx-code/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/matrix.c:196: undefined reference to `_spotrf_'
/usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.a(matrix.o): In function `solve':
/cygdrive/c/Downloads/src/cmusphinx-code/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/matrix.c:226: undefined reference to `_sposv_'
/usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.a(matrix.o): In function `invert':
/cygdrive/c/Downloads/src/cmusphinx-code/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/matrix.c:254: undefined reference to `_sposv_'
/usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.a(matrix.o): In function `matrixmultiply':
/cygdrive/c/Downloads/src/cmusphinx-code/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/matrix.c:272: undefined reference to `_ssymm_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:420: recipe for target `sphinx3_decode.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [sphinx3_decode.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Downloads/src/cmusphinx-code/sphinx3/src/programs'
Makefile:284: recipe for target `all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Downloads/src/cmusphinx-code/sphinx3/src'
Makefile:407: recipe for target `all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

The problem does not appear to be that the cmu sphinx library `liblsphinxbase.a` cannot be found. Rather that there is something wrong with that library. I've run the `nm` command on this library and this is *all* I got (seems rather empty).

```
nm libsphinxbase.a | grep _spotrf_
U _spotrf_
```

Should the flag `-llapack` be added to the link step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the failed step with `llapack` and it works. It appears that `-llapack` needs to be added to the link command.